# User control (ASCX) turned into Binary code

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ascx

I had working ascx code, but today when I viewed ascx file content is showed in binary. Can someone tell me what happened? And how can I get back my ascx file. Of course, I can get from source control but I want to know what is solution of current problem.
Here is what looks like my code. It is small part of file of course.
[image]

Comment: Maybe related: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479318.aspx#customcontrolfromusercontrol_topic5

Comment: I did not publish website after my last changes. What could happen? Can't understand

Comment: Looks like it's not just binary (which all fines are anyways) but 0'd out. We could spend all day trying to figure this out. It could be some random program. Could be a strange goof of the computer. Could be malware. Anyways, the easiest thing to do is just retrieve it from source control and move on. If it happens again, then investigate more carefully.

Comment: It is so strange. File can be opened with binary editor just, and binary data is invalid. In whole solution just one file has this problem. It is so interesting what happened? My system has no malware. Wow, This kind of problem is first time in my life.